# When is $GL_m(R)$ generated by elementary and diagonal matrices?

Tags: matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory, division-algebras

Let $D$ be a division ring and $R=D[t_1,\ldots,t_n]$ the polynomial ring in $n$ variables. Now let $GL_m(R),\,E_m(R)$ be the usual general linear group and its subgroup generated by the elementary matrices of the form $I_m+r\epsilon(i,j)$ ($r\in R$). Further, by $U(R)$ I mean the units of $R$. This may be confused with $GL_1(R)$ in a natural way. My question is this, when is $GL_m(R)=U(R)\cdot E_m(R)$, i.e. when can any $X\in GL_m(R)$ be written as a product of elementary matrices (up to a unit)?

I know that, by a result of Cohn, that $GL_2(R)\neq U(R)\cdot E_2(R)$, but what about the case when $m>2$? If $D$ was commutative then we could obviously apply Suslin's stability theorem, but as far as I know this is not true for the case of division rings.

Comment: If $D$ is commutative you don't need any theorem: computing the determinant trivially implies $E_n(R)\neq GL_n(R)$. Or do you mean something else? Suslin's theorem indeed says that $E_n(R)=SL_n(R)$.

Comment: @YCor What I mean is, any invertible matrix $X$ can be written as a product of elementary matrixes $X=E_1\ldots E_t$ (give or take some unit)

Comment: Yes: I just said that this is trivially false in the case $D$ is commutative, because of the determinant condition.

Comment: By the way you should use two different letters for the size of matrices and the number of indeterminates, unless you really want them to match for any precise reason.

Comment: @YCor Thanks, I fixed the typesetting. Well it isn't false for $D$ commutative. In this case $GL_m(R)=U(R)SL_m(R)$. Now, if $m\geq 3$ then Suslin's stability theorem tells us $SL_m(R)=E_m(R)$. So, any $X\in GL_m(R)$ can be written as a product of elementary matrices (up to a unit). By the way, I am writing the units of $R$ as $U(R)$.

Comment: Just to clarify: when you write $D[t_1,\ldots,t_n]$, do you mean that the $t_i$ commute with each other (and with all scalars)?

Comment: @R. van Dobben de Bruyn Yep, I mean commuting variables

Comment: @SamWilliams it's still a bit vague. $U(R)$ is contained in $R^\times$. How do you embed it into $GL_m$? The element $r\in R^\times$ could correspond to the scalar matrix $(r,r,\dots,r)$, or to $(r,1,\dots,1)$, which is not equivalent.

Comment: @YCor (Unless $R=\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$.)

Comment: @YCor As far as I know, it is quite natural to embed $U(R)$ into $GL_m(R)$ by considering $U(R)$ as $GL_1(R)$ and mapping $GL_m(R)$ into $GL_{m+1}(R)$ via the stabilization $X\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}X&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @YCor I also edited the question to hopefully make it a bit clearer what I mean.

Comment: OK; this lengthy discussion would have been avoided if you had asked whether $GL_m(R)$ is generated by elementary and diagonal (invertible) matrices.

Comment: @YCor It seemed obvious that that is what I was asking, particularly when I said (up to a unit). But hopefully now we can agree on what I am asking?

Comment: @Sam I agree it seems it was obvious to you, which is a good start. It wasn't to me, as you might have noticed. As regards your second question, the answer is clear from my previous comment :)

Comment: @YCor Yeah, pitfalls of staring at something for too long. Thanks for the input. Hopefully now the question is clear to all.

Comment: The question would look much better if the embedding of $U(R)$ was there, _and_ it is not too late to fix this.

Answer (score -3):

If $D$ is a field then every matrix of $\mathrm{SL}_m(R)$ can be written as product of elementary matrices for $m$ not equal to 2, because for $m=2$ Cohn gives an example which contradict this result. For $\mathrm{GL}_m(R)$ how you can say?

Comment: You could have read the comments before posting. You were also misled by the unclear wording of the question.

Comment: @Ram Krishna Verma you just repeated what I asked in the question